# SLES 11SP4 LDAP - error trying to bind as user - (Invalid credentials)

Tags: pam, ldap, sles

I have LDAP server configured (with YaST) on SLES 11SP4 and I've created 3 users. I can su (from root) to any of the user but I cannot login as any of them or change their passwords.

When I tried to log on (using su as standard user) in /var/log/messages I have:

```
suse1 su: pam_ldap: error trying to bind as user "uid=user3,dc=linux" (Invalid credentials)
suse1 su: FAILED SU (to user3) root on /dev/pts/0
```

When I tried change the password in /var/log/messages:

```
suse1 passwd[5864]: pam_unix2(passwd:chauthtok): user "user1" does not exist in /etc/passwd or NIS
suse1 passwd[5864]: pam_ldap: error trying to bind as user "uid=user1,dc=linux" (Invalid credentials)
```

My /etc/pam.d/common-password:

```
password        requisite       pam_pwcheck.so  nullok cracklib 
password        sufficient      pam_unix2.so    use_authtok nullok 
password        required        pam_ldap.so     try_first_pass use_authtok
```

My /etc/pam.d/common-auth:

```
auth    required        pam_env.so      
auth    sufficient      pam_unix2.so    
auth    required        pam_ldap.so     use_first_pass
```

I cannot find out what is wrong and the password I used for sure is correct. Thanks for any hint.

Answer (score 0):

On my case if it could help, I forgot to add the `ldap` module into `/etc/nsswitch.conf`

```
# /etc/nsswitch.conf
#
# Example configuration of GNU Name Service Switch functionality.
# If you have the `glibc-doc-reference' and `info' packages installed, try:
# `info libc "Name Service Switch"' for information about this file.

passwd:         compat ldap
group:          compat ldap
shadow:         compat ldap
gshadow:        files ldap
```